# Can't upload world to a realm Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I am trying to upload a world with a datapack to my realm so that that realm may have a datapack. This stopped at 2.4% and then said "Upload Failed! -1"
This made me think I jsut couldn't upload worlds with datapacks to my realm. So, I created a completely new world called test, and then I left and attempted to upload THAT to realms. It failed, stopping at 2.4% again with the exact same error message. I can't upload ANY world to my realms, which is really annoying. Is there a way to fix this?
[image: This is an image of the error message.]

My internet is fine, but I can't test this on another device for the time being. My firewall should be okay, it's fully open for Minecraft. I can create new worlds, but I just can't upload any.

Comment: The usual questions: Do you have an internet connection, is there a firewall/antivirus/…, is your internet reasonably fast, does the same happen on another device/network/…?

Answer (score 1):

reload minecraft, it happens to me every time I cancel an upload and try another one afterwards. If you reload the minecraft launcher it should work properly again afterwards